# Click On Element Using RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I am using RSelenium and having a challenge with clicking an item.

Unfortunately, the webpage is password protected so I cannot send a link to the page. I want to click on All Positions in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of page]

Below is the html code for the section:.

```
    <div id=""""subtabs-A38109645-1e53-11e8-a6a9-005056b27f7d"""" """"="""""""" data-dojo-type=""""retail/widget/SubTabs"""" lang=""""en-US"""" widgetid=""""subtabs-A38109645-1e53-11e8-a6a9-005056b27f7d"""" class=""""subTabControl"""">"
        <span data-subtab=""""Asset type"""" class=""""subTab selected"""">Asset type</span>"
        <span data-subtab=""""All positions"""" class=""""subTab """">All positions</span>"
        <span class=""""spinner""""></span>"
    </div>"
```

I have used this code to isolate the section, but am not sure what to do next to be able to use clickElement().

```
remDr$findElements(using = "class name", "subTabControl")
```

If I was doing this manually, I would simply click on "All positions" to get what I wanted.

Looking at this site, http://robertmyles.github.io/2016/04/27/web-navigation-in-r-with-rselenium/, he mentions that chrome gives the option to copy the xpath or css selector (“selector”)

So I am trying these 2 lines, also without success:

```
webElem1 <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", "#subtabs-A233d64aa-1e6b-11e8-a693-005056b25ffb > span:nth-child(2)")
webElem1$clickElement()

webElem2 <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="subtabs-A89e1602a-1e6c-11e8-a693-005056b25ffb"]/span[2]')
webElem2$clickElement()
```

I receive this error in both cases:

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing `findElements` to `findElement`? IIRC, the first one returns a list (of one element in this case) and not a single element.

Comment: That helped, thank you. Unfortunately, it appears the element is dynamic, the "a693", present in both the css and xpath seems to change with each login. I will have to use a different source for the info I'd like to download. Either that, or isolate the "a693" each time and then paste it in.

Comment: I solved this problem by using firefox instead of chrome. I was able to easily use the css example above and click it without error.